# Failed to install rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a new Rails application. After I ran the command

```
rails new $APP_NAME -T —database=postgresql
```

This error occurs:

> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
>   /Users/$USER_NAME/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rails-5.1.4/README.md
>   An error occurred while installing rails (5.1.4), and Bundler
>   cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install rails -v '5.1.4'` succeeds before bundling.

I have installed Rails (version 5.1.4) but if I run `rails -v` in my app directory it is not working because it is asking me to run `bundle install` which if I do gives me the same error as mentioned above. I checked my Gemfile and there is the Rails gem.

But if I go to bin/rails there is a problem. Here it is not recognising the Ruby (version 2.3.5) code. Only giving me this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require ‘rails/commands'
```

This is my first application with a new computer so I might have done something wrong with the setup or installation but I also tried to uninstall/install Rails again. I really tried a lot and don’t know what could be the issue. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which Rails version did you install? 5.4.1? that version doesn't exist - still, can you see what's in the output of `gem list --local | grep rails`?

Comment: sorry I meant version 5.1.4 and if I run the gem list i get:
> coffee-rails (4.2.2)
> rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
> rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
> sprockets-rails (3.2.1)

Comment: There's no Rails there, can you try by running `gem install rails`, this should install the latest version 5.1.4, then run the previous command again.

Comment: If i run it this error occurs: 

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/$USER_NAME/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rails-5.1.4/README.md

Comment: Have you tried giving permission to the `.rbenv`, or in last case by using sudo?

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked using sudo, still don't really understand why it happend in the first place but at least now it is working! Thank you! The only thing is that in my .bin/rails file the code didn't change and is different to the one of previous applications and I don't know if this will be a problem.

Comment: Maybe because of different Rails version?, most probably you installed rbenv by using sudo or any other unaccessible user, you could try by giving permissions to the folder to not worry about the sudo.

Comment: @SebastianPalma please post your response as the correct answer.